# How to extract files correctly to install twilio in windows powershell?

Tags: twilio

I am using these command in windows powers shell

```
scoop bucket add twilio-scoop https://github.com/twilio/scoop-twilio-cli
>> scoop install twilio
```

And I'm getting this error

```
Failed to extract files from C:\Users\fookyao\scoop\apps\twilio\5.18.0\twilio-win32-x64.tar.
Log file:
  ~\scoop\apps\twilio\5.18.0\7zip.log

Please try again or create a new issue by using the following link and paste your console output:
https://github.com/twilio/scoop-twilio-cli/issues/new?title=twilio%405.18.0%3a+decompress+error
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What errors are you seeing when you look in that log file at `~\scoop\apps\twilio\5.18.0\7zip.log` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once scoop is installed, you need to restart your powershell as an administrator and run the code again.